# From JSON file to related typeORM entities

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Let's say I have a backend that needs to be able to receive big JSON files containing data.

This JSON data should be decomposed into several different tables/entities (in order to be easily manipulated by a frontend).

Those different entities should be in relation to each other (one-to-many/many-to-one relations).

In your opinion, what's the best way populate a db from a JSON file, using nest js and typeORM ?

Thanks in advance for your knowledge,
4coma

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is unclear. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: thanks, I modified the formulation of the question

Answer (score 0):

you mean fast define entities from a json file.

If right, I usually use app https://app.quicktype.io/ to convert json file to interface type (select language Typescript and interface only)

Then use editor replace `interface` to `class`

replace with expression `;\n` to `;\n\n\t@Column()\n`

replace with expression `export class` to `@Entity()\n export class`

then import decorator Column, Entity, add option to column as you need